# Detecting gestures on overlapping screen areas in iOS5

Tags: ipad, ios5, uigesturerecognizer

As shown in the diagram below, my app has a few UIViews, `B`, `C` and `D`, side by side, and all contained in an enveloping UIView `A`:

[image]

I have a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` in each of `B`, `C`, and `D`. What I'd also like to do is recognize a different gesture over the entire of area `A` (without hindering the other gesture recognizers from working).

What's the best strategy for this? I'm targeting iOS5+, no backwards compatability needed.

It's also worth noting that the gesture recognizer for `A` will probably have to be a custom gesture recognizer, since I want to detect a pinch but with > 2 fingers involved.

**Thought:**

If installing a gesture recognizer for `A` doesn't work well, it might be possible to do it the old way by using `touchesBegan` etc. As the [`UIResponder` docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) note, you can have an subclass of `UIView` just call `[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]` to have it passed on in the responder chain if you're not interested in the touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out just adding gesture recognizers in the straightforward obvious way works, at least for the gestures I want to recognize. I imagined it would be more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Add the GestureRecognize to A as you would normally do.

Now you need to start by hit-testing what was touched.

First you need to test the z-index of the items. For example if you touch B, then your function will loop/hit-test over all the items that are affected, in this case A & B.
After your function detects both A & B (B over A) hit-test, it should check for the z-index. For example B's z-index is 2, then A z-index is 1. Now you know that the B is what the user intended to touch because it's z-index is higher and this means that it is on-top.

After you have the target identified(the B), before executing it's GestureRecognize you need to temporarily disable the GestureRecognize for A to eliminate any conflict between the overlapping GestureRecognizes. After the B touch completes/ends, enable A's GestureRecognize back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Hit testing in which component/piece of code? Using which technique? (e.g. touchesBegan etc)?

Comment: I do't have a code that I can post as is, but I will try to explain.
Use both Touches as initial touch identification and GestureRecognizes as secondary handler for touch inside the identified component. 
On initial touch hit test the whole screen. Loop thru all your elements and find which of them are located within the touched coordinates. So if you touched B, the loop should find B and A as both are within the contact coordinates. Then you can disable/enable  the conflicting GestureRecognizes and after the gesture completes, enable them back.